# create a visual studio toolbox styled tool

Tags: wpf, qt, user-interface

This is more of a generic question. I was wondering how it is possible to create a visual studio toolbox type tool, from where you can drag and drop buttons to your workspace. I guess this is similar to how Matlab-Simulink allows you to add blocks. I was looking for the name of  what that is called. Can such a tool be created using WPF or Qt?

Comment: What do you know about drag-n-drop in Qt, and what you already tried?

Comment: As @DmitrySazonov states, it's just drag and drop. However, Qt Creator supports this too, so you can download and look at the source code: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt-Creator-from-Git